# Is it possible to change the default configuration of the default Camera app in android?

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I'm creating an app in which I got one button and when clicking on it, I open the default camera app of the device using the following code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                //do sth;
            }
        });

 Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 activityResultLauncher.launch(pictureIntent);
```

So in this case I am using **MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** passed to the **Intent** and this allows me to take a picture and get the result back with the help of **ActivityResultLauncher**.

Now, Is there any way to **change** the **default settings** of the default app of **Camera** by passing some specific **parameters** for example, image size, etc..?

[image]

This is the screen that I get when opening the default camera app, so Is there any way to **hide** one of the **buttons** above or at least make it **un-clickable**?

Comment: If you want that level of control over the image capture process, then chances are you simply want to create the activity to take the picture yourself and not delegate that to the default application (which can vary wildly from device to device)

Comment: @JoachimSauer 
Yes, I think I'll end up doing that if there is no way to control the default app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, Is there any way to change the default settings of the default app of Camera by passing some specific parameters for example, image size, etc..?

First, there is no single "default app of Camera". There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of default camera apps across the tens of thousands of Android device models. Also, on most older Android versions, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` can be used to launch the user's own installed camera app.

Second, the only ["specific parameters" documented for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore#action_image_capture) is `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

> This is the screen that I get when opening the default camera app

That is the screen that you get when opening *a* camera app on *a* device. There are many, many camera apps that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` can launch — what you get will depend on the device.

> so Is there any way to hide one of the buttons above or at least make it un-clickable?

There is no requirement for a camera app to have those buttons. Or a camera app can have more buttons. FWIW, I own several dozen Android devices, and I do not recall seeing a camera app with that particular UI before.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way you can configure the screen of native android app. We can only pass the URI where the image needs to be saved and size of image.

If you would like to create your own layout, it is possible. You can refer to this repo [Open Camera](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera), especially this class [AlmalenceGUI](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera/blob/master/src/com/almalence/opencam/ui/AlmalenceGUI.java) which has icon arrangements.